# Android app is slow - public static class variables

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

My Android app has 7 fragment classes; one with a WebView, one with the camera showing on a SurfaceView, one with Google Maps and the others with ListViews which contain images and text.

Each Fragment has around 15 public static class variables.  Is this bad programming?

It seems my app is fairly slow and i'm wondering if it's to do with having so many public static class variables.

Any tips on how to speed up my Android app?  Will it make much of an improvement to speed if i moved as many of these public class variables into methods and functions instead of having them as class variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really depends-  why are those values public static?  Are they constants?  Something else?  The fact that they have a lot of statics won't slow down your program, but if they're variables, you probably are doing something wrong-  its very rare to need a static variable in a Fragment, unless its a constant.

Comment: Most likely `static` variables won't cause significant slowing of your app. You need to find tools to measure the slowness. Is the UI unresponsive? Is there a certain task that runs for longer than you expect?

Comment: The UI isn't unresponsive, although on devices with 1gb of ram it lags a little bit.  I'm just wondering if static class variables use a lot of memory which may be slowing down the app.  I'm fairly sure that's the issue, but i thought i'd get some other opinions before i start spending my whole day restructuring my code.

Comment: Gabe, thanks for your response.  The variables aren't constants, most of them are to hold views which are accessed from various methods and functions within the fragment that the layout that contains the view relates to.  Some are public static views which are accessed from other fragments too.  From your answer i'm guessing storing views in public static class variables is not the right way to go about it.

Comment: Ok, allowing static access to Views is always a *bad* idea.  Views are associated with a single instance of a fragment.  Even if your design is such that you won't reuse a fragment elsewhere, there are several situations where you may have 2 different copies in memory temporarily-  the statics could refer to the wrong one.  And if you're actually using the fragment in multiple places you're really going to have problems.  They also could cause memory to be held for longer than needed or even leaked permanently.

Comment: Thanks Gabe!  Awesome answer!  The fragments are not reused so i haven't had any problems other than the app being slow.  I assumed the speed issue was because of what you said, views in memory being held for much longer than needed.  Thanks for confirming and for the super fast response!

Answer (score 2):

> Each Fragment has around 15 public static class variables. Is this bad programming?

Probably. If this were traditional Java development, you might be burned at the stake for having that many `static` fields. In Android, we use them a *bit* more. 15 for any class is excessive; I would expect a fragment to have zero.

Though, to clarify, based on Gabe's comment to your question, I am referring to normal `static` fields, not constants (e.g., `static final int`, `static final String`). Constants are typical, reasonable, and almost assuredly not a performance issue.

> It seems my app is fairly slow and i'm wondering if it's to do with having so many public static class variables.

Probably not.

> Any tips on how to speed up my Android app?

You start by figuring out **specifically** where you are slow. Whether that is through simple `Log` statements (to track your progress through your app), through Android Studio method tracing, or something else, is up to you.

Comment: IMO static objects affects the build time and dalvik/art process time only. So the app would be a little bit slower at starting than the ones use less static object. But that mount of time doesn't really matter IMO

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, Good info.  Nguyễn you are correct, the app does take a while to start (about 4 seconds), which is too long.  I'll work on moving my variables (which are mainly views) away from static class variables and that should make the app open quicker, and hopefully run faster.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Points to be considered for optimization

1 - In your app I could see you have 7 fragments. Questions is whether all 7 fragments loaded at the same time or do you have dynamic Fragment Manager to handle all data/view creation as and when needed. If you are loading and creating all fragments at the same time, definitely, this is not the optimal way. Always create view and load data as and when needed. Persist dynamic data which are really historical and necessary for App flow.

2 - Having static class is not bad programing but making unnecessary static class is really bad programing. Identify classes which you considered to be non-static, convert it non-static and optimize further.

3 - You may feel app is slow but there may be non-technical reason behind it. Check which device, platform and configuration you are using to run this app.

4 - Identify data processing which are holding and blocking UI response, create asyncTask/thread to handle such data processing in background. Try to use Lazy loading wherever possible. Create custom adapters with static holders to make flawless UI.

5 - If you feel UI is non-responsive, you can think of multiple patterns to be implemented like recycle Adapter, Chain-of-responsibility, delegation, observers and so on..

6 - While designing UI, make sure you are using optimal layouts rather than use of multilevel and multi-hierarchical layouts within same xml.

Comment: Hi Rekesh, thanks for that info. I have done pretty much all of that already to optimize.  The fragments aren't dynamic, i tried making them dynamic but the UX is much better (imo) when they are already loading, navigating feels a lot more fluid.  I think the issue i'm having is i'm that i'm storing views in static class variables and it's using a lot of memory. Your points are great though, i'm sure it will help someone else who views this post!

Answer (score 0):

you can add this

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

on your application tag in AndroidManifest. Hope this was helpful